# "no such file or directory" for filenames with accents on ntfs hard drive on mac os x

Tags: macos, mac, ntfs, encoding

I'm on OSX El Capitan (10.11.3) and i plugged an external hard drive in a NTFS format. I have troubles reading some files with 'accents'.

```
bash> ls
Document re´ponse - Partie 2.docx   Test métier.pdf
```

And when i do `ls -l`:

```
bash> ls -l
ls: Test métier.pdf: No such file or directory
total 1600
-rwxr-xr-x  2 guillaumethomas  staff  323153  8 mar  2009 Document re´ponse - Partie 2.docx
```

I guess there are issues with the encoding since:

```
python> import os
python> os.listdir('.')
['Document re\xc2\xb4ponse - Partie 2.docx', 'Test me\xcc\x81tier.pdf']
python> map(lambda s: s.decode('Utf8'), os.listdir('.'))
[u'Document re\xb4ponse - Partie 2.docx', u'Test me\u0301tier.pdf']
```

Both filenames are encoded in utf8 and:

- file 1 uses the *acute accent* with the [U+00B4 unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b4/index.htm)
- file 2 uses the *combining acute accent* with the [U+0301 unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm)

My best guess here is that the encoding is the root cause of all that mess. Several questions:
  - Do you think it's the case?
  - How can i solve this issue?
  - How can i be sure that the file exists (`file`, `du` commands all gives `No such file or directory` errors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MacOS X is not able to read filenames with combining accents as mentioned here:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3545860?tstart=0

I wasn't able to figure out why.

I fixed it by modifying the filenames under linux with python unicodedata normalize function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize